# MS Access error: Could not find file "." when transfering from old SP to SP365

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I'm trying to transfer a ton of data from an old sharepoint platform through access to sharepoint 365.

When I do this, I get an error like this:

[Picture of access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdNZ2.jpg)

As far as I can tell, this means that theres either a server problem, or something was misspelled.

I can transfer several other views without any problems, so im hoping that someone out there can shed some light on this.

Comment: that doesn't tell us anything. try opening the specific view in SharePoint and try export/open in access. any errors from that view?

Comment: The error occours when importing the specific view in access, sorry if I didnt speficy enough. I'm not that used to using these programs.

Comment: Either you can open access and link sharepoint/views as external table (your picture is showing it) or you can open the SharePoint view and click "open in Access" which will do the same but SP will put the correct view name address. also when you say old sp what version is it?

Comment: I'm exporting lists from sharepoint 2007 to 365. Also if I link it in access, all the fields are just shown as #Deleted. I don't know about the last part with opening access through SP, never heard of it or tried it, should I attempt to do this? And if so, how :)

Answer (score 0):

Cause of this problem can be in names of attachments. Just now I had the same problem importing the SP2007 list to Access and I find out, that I can import everything except two records with attachment, which name contained + symbol. I had to delete the attachment, then the import was OK.
Bigger problem was to find problematic records - I had to make special view filtered by date of last change and then tryied importing records from different time scopes, until I identified records causing the trouble.